# setkomafont section title colour not printing

Tags: color, koma-script, printing

I have the following code in my custom class:

```
\RequirePackage{anyfontsize}
\RequirePackage{libertine}
\RequirePackage[libertine,liby,cmintegrals,cmbraces,vvarbb]{newtxmath}
\RequirePackage[scaled=0.95,varqu,varl]{inconsolata}
\RequirePackage[left=2cm,right=5.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{microtype}

\definecolor{structure}{rgb}{0.09,0.09,0.44}
\setkomafont{title}{\normalfont\Large\sffamily\color{structure}}
\setkomafont{author}{\normalfont\sffamily}
\setkomafont{date}{\normalfont\sffamily}
\setkomafont{section}{\normalfont\large\sffamily\color{structure}}
\setkomafont{subsection}{\normalfont\sffamily\color{structure}}
```

Everything works fine on screen, with titles and sections in dark blue. But when I print the document, the title and sections are printed in black. Subsections (and theorem titles, which are set by different code), are printed correctly in dark blue.

Any idea how to fix this and what is wrong?

**Update: (non-)working example**

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[scaled=0.95,varqu,varl]{inconsolata}

\definecolor{structure}{rgb}{0.09,0.09,0.44}

\setkomafont{title}{\normalfont\Large\sffamily\color{structure}}
\setkomafont{section}{\normalfont\large\sffamily\color{structure}}
\setkomafont{subsection}{\normalfont\sffamily\color{structure}}

\title{Test}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Foobar}

\subsection{Bazquk}

\end{document}
```

[image: Printing result]

However, if I remove the libertine and inconsolata lines, I do get correct colouring in the printout. So what is going on with those fonts?

Comment: No clue without an example. Could you provide an MWE?

Comment: Added, includig photo.

Comment: Does the print depend on the colour? Is it still wrong, if you choose another colour, say `0,0.8,0.1`?

Comment: I changed 'structure' to 'red' inside \color, and the result is still the same (with '1.1 Bazquk' obviously in red, but the rest in black).

Comment: Can you provide more info about your OS and the software you are using to print? There is a bug in Windows 10 or Arcobat Reader, which is really strange: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2210106

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and Evince.

Comment: qpdfview has the same problems

Comment: I have no idea, what could cause this really strange result. Sorry.

Comment: An update of texlive has fixed the issue.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not reproducible with any current TeX distribution.